# What does "stochastic" mean in RBM networks?

Tags: autoencoders, restricted-boltzmann-machine

I am learning about restricted Boltzmann machines (RBM). It is still unclear to me why it is a stochastic algorithm. I was wondering if some one can explain it with comparison to deterministic ones (like autoencoders).

For example, [here](https://www.edureka.co/blog/restricted-boltzmann-machine-tutorial/) says `RBM shares a similar idea, but it uses stochastic units with particular distribution instead of deterministic distribution.`

Comment: Regular autoencoders are deterministic because, once you have trained them, for a given input you always get the same output. RBM, on the contrary, have stochastic units that are sampled each time you ask for an output, hence they are stochastic (they are in fact a generative model).

Answer (score 0):

An autoencoder is a deterministic function which maps input $x$ to output $\hat x = f(x; \theta)$ -- $\theta$ being the network parameters.

An RBM is a pair of sets of random variables $(v,h)$, whose joint distribution takes a "quadratic" form -- $\frac{1}{Z} \exp \left( v^T Wh + a^Tv + b^Th\right)$.

Curiously, $p(h_i|v) = \sigma(b+W^Tv)_i$, and all $h_i$ are independent conditioned on $v$. This closely mimics the computation of a neural network -- however I would be extremely cautious of thinking of an RBM as a type of feedforward neural network -- this is likely to lead to confusion. The tutorial you linked isn't particularly good. [This](https://christian-igel.github.io/paper/TRBMAI.pdf) may help.